# How to align images and text in same line?

Tags: graphics, align, png

I am trying to align 3 images and text such that text is left aligned and images are all right aligned but can't figure out how to do it. Following is the code snipped I have written for the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{2.6in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{\Large Shreyas Mangalgi} \\
\end{tabular*}

\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{IIMC.png}
    \includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{ISI.png}
    \includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{IITKGP.png}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output :

[image]

While I want the output to be something like this :

[image]

I am unable to figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: Why don't put the images in the second column of the tabular?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{\Large Shreyas Mangalgi}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{IIMC.png}
\includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{ISI.png}
\includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{IITKGP.png}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The text is flush left, the images are flush right. The white space to the left and right is the normal white border of the page.

The same effect can be obtained with a `tabular`. Note the use of `@{}` to remove extra space to the left and right of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
  \textbf{\Large Shreyas Mangalgi}
&
  \includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{IIMC.png}
  \includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{ISI.png}
  \includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{IITKGP.png}
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```